# How to set two image view for CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an `ImagePickerController` for photo and video. When I pick photo or video from camera I display it in a `CollectionView` as image. At this step everything works. I add a `Bool` variable `checkVideo` to know what image I have in cell, image from video or photo. `checkVideo` change value when I use imagePickerController for video or photo. I want to add a new image with the play icon for images which comes from video. Here is my code :

```
- (CustomCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (checkVideo == YES) {

        UIImageView *playVideoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        playVideoImageView.image = playImg;
        [cell addSubview:playVideoImageView];
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
        checkVideo = NO;
    } else {
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
    }
    NSLog(@"check video %@", checkVideo ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: where do you set this `checkVideo` flag? Is it a single variable or an `array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make two prototypes, instead of one:
MyCell1 and MyCell2 in your storyboard's collectionView Scene, then:

```
- (CustomCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // previously, you were using the same variable, that always had the same value for each row... 
    // you should grab a value from your prepared array like this:

    Bool checkVideo = checkVideoArray[indexPath.row]

    if (checkVideo == YES) {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];        
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];

        // in your prototype MyCell2 you now have to add one more subView like 'playImageView'
        // don't forget to link it via @IBOutlet too
        // reuse handling will be safe here - because if you were adding subview each time in cellForRow method, the image wouldn't be handled properly and it would be re-adding a layer on layer, what wouldn't be OK
        cell.playImageView.image = playImg;                         
    } else {
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
    }
    NSLog(@"check video %@", checkVideo ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I try to use your solution but i have the same result, when i take photo everything alright but when use video the play icon adds for all cells. But i have one more question. If i use xib i should add another custom cell for play image(icon) or i can use only one custom cell and just register nib '     [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell2"];'

Comment: I didn't notice, we forgot to get a right value for your checkVideo variable. Check update.

Comment: @DmitriyBabinskiy My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you might be using a single `Boolean` variable `checkVideo` for distinguishing videos and photos. That may be why it works fine for photos, but when a video is recorded, all the images are casted as videos with the Play button. So probably you may need to redesign your flag into a Boolean Array.
Set the flag as shown.

```
[checkVideo replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
```

or by using @(YES) which wraps a BOOL in an NSNumber

```
[checkVideo replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:@(YES)]]
```

Now you may check the value of `checkVideo` flag instance corresponding to the cell under consideration by pulling out the boolValue from the array.

BOOL video = [[checkVideo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];

```
if video == YES{
    //do your stuff here
}
```

PS: Please do state all these facts in the question or answer the clarifications in the comments. This will help in pin pointing the exact error.

Comment: I init a mutablearray and added into it the bool values, but when try to compare as you write i have a warning **Comparison between pointer and integer ('id' and 'int')** my code ' if (checkVideoArray[indexPath.row] == YES)'

Comment: added that too in the answer

Comment: Thank for answer! I solve my problem from @pedrouan solution. But your solution right too! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry i can't add two answer :( but i grateful you for help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue you are facing at present ?

You can add one image view in your custom cell and based on checkvideo bool that image will be hidden.

```
- (CustomCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (checkVideo == YES) {

      /*  UIImageView *playVideoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        playVideoImageView.image = playImg;
        [cell addSubview:playVideoImageView];*/
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
        checkVideo = NO;
    } else {
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
    }
    NSLog(@"check video %@", checkVideo ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

//You can hide or show play image based on below line.
        cell.playimage.hidden = !checkVideo;

```
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I try this approach if i take photo firstly the play button doesn't show its correct but when i record video the play button shows at all cells

Comment: if  i change my code as  ' if (checkVideo == YES) {
            cell.playImage.hidden = !checkVideo;
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.imageViewCell.image = arrayForImages[indexPath.row];
    }
checkVideo = NO;
    return cell;'  now play icon added at first cell when i record video and after adding photo play icon shifted to 1, 2, ,3  cell etc.

Comment: as You are managing Only One bool to show Video or not. 
If there will be multiple rows then definitely there will be issue,You need to manage  arrayForVideo which will have same no of bool objects as arrayforimage .

Your Condition will be
 if ([arrayForVideo objectatindex item] == YES)